Long boot time (loader takes ~3 mins) 24.04 LTS
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS onto an external SSD (Adata Elite 500 GB) with all component too (boot etc)
CPU: i7 9700K
RAM: 32 GB
GPU: i7 9700K + RTX 4070
SSD tested in USB 3.1 and 3.2 as well with same results.
Once it's started the performance is great.
Primarily using the igpu as planning to passtrough the dedicated to a VM.
Symptoms: Enter UEFI boot menu and chose the SSD to boot. Grub menu pops up hit enter and 3 minutes black screen. After that the Loginscreen jumps in.
system-analyze result:
Startup finished in 18.444s (firmware) + 2min 56.272s (loader) + 3.146s (kernel) + 8.269s (userspace) = 3min 26.133s
graphical.target reached after 8.257s in userspace.  

Have no idea what is the loader part. systemd-analyze blame and systemd-analyze critical-chain don't contain value related to this.
The blame first few lines:
5.749s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
5.187s plymouth-quit-wait.service
1.073s gpu-manager.service

bootctl says:
System:
 Firmware: n/a (n/a)
 Firmware Arch: x64
 Secure Boot: disabled (setup)
 TPM2 Support: no
 Measured UKI: no
 Boot into FW: supported

Any idea what can I check and how to solve it? What is this loader phase actually?

Did you find a solution to this? Happening the same for me with a Kingston XS2000 500GB, USB 3.2

I think it was because I booted from external external drive (I used simple usb 3.1 pendrive in the past successfully). I moved to internal drive which solved it
